# Using backslash to escape characters in cmd.exe (runas command as example)

Tags: windows, shell, cmd.exe

I see that the caret is the documented escape character.

But, I have an example showing that for the double quote character, `^` doesn't work and you have to use `\`

```
C:\>runas /user:Administrator "cmd /k dir \"%userprofile%\""
```

Why is that, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the examples in `RUNAS /?` shows that syntax. The caret is the escape character for `CMD.EXE` but in Windows individual programs are free to implement their own escape characters and globbing.

Comment: interesting.. and btw.. what is cmd.exe doing with the unescaped quotes at the end? does it keep them, if so why.. Or does it remove them.. if so,  why were they needed in the first place?

Comment: @barlop: See Michael's [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/182454/cmd-exe-escape-character-caret-ok-but-what-about-backslash/182519#182519).

Comment: are you sure \" is being interpreted by runas and not by cmd.exe? compiling this w.c http://pastebin.com/28Q2Wxxr  to w.exe   Compare a)w "a a"  b)w \"a a\"  c)w ^"a a^"    Notice what happens with b in particular. I guess that's the cmd shell treating \ as an escape character.

Comment: while it hasn't been cmd.exe that interpreted it, it's not the program either, it's the runtime that split args. i'm not sure if one would call that the program being free to implement it. more like the way the compiler implemented it, or the way the compiler implements it for the programs. any programs written in i suppose, ms visual c, would parse argsv "thusly" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx

Answer (score 17):

In cmd, `\` does **not** escape `"`. Here's a quick proof and explanation:

1. Run `echo "" & echo 1`. (`&` is a special char in cmd, `left & right` means run `left` then run `right`.) We can see that both `echo ""` and `echo 1` are run successfully.
2. Next, run `echo " & 1234`. We can see that the output is `" & 1234`. This is because the opening `"` has not been closed, and thus everything after it is interpreted as a string, including the special char `&`.
3. Run `echo "\" & 1234`.

   - If `\` does escape the following `"`, the opening `"` will not be closed and the chars `& 1234` will be interpreted as part of the string.
   - If `\` fails to escape the following `"`, *that* following `"` will close the string and `& 1234` will **not** be interpreted as part of the string.

   In the output, we do not see `& 1234` interpreted as part of the string. **This proves that `\` has failed to escape `"`.**

So what escapes `"` within quotes for argument passing? While `^` will work outside of quotes (easily proven via `echo ^" & echo 1`),  it does not escape quotes within quotes.

Indeed, how can we get something as simple as `echo """` `&` `echo 1` to work?

The `^` char? ...Nope, `echo "^"" & echo 1` outputs `"^""`, and not `"""`.

What about the `"` char itself? ...Nope,  `echo """" & echo 1`  outputs `""""`, and not `"""`.

The fact is, **there's nothing that will escape `"` within quotes for argument passing**. You can brood over this for a couple of years and arrive at no solution. This is just some of the inherent limitations of cmd scripting.

However, the good news is that you'll most likely *never* come across a situation whereby you need to do so. Sure, there's no way to get `echo """` `&` `echo 1` to work, but that's not such a big deal because it's simply a contrived problem which you'll likely never encounter.

For example, consider `runas`. It works fine without needing to escape `"` within quotes  because **`runas` knew** that there's no way to do so and  made internal adjustments to work around it. `runas` invented its own parsing rules (`runas /flag "anything even including quotes"`) and does not interpret cmd arguments the usual way.  Official documentation for these special syntax is pretty sparse (or non-existent). Aside from `/?` and `help`, it's mostly trial-and-error.

Comment: Quick testing, `echo ^"^"^" &  echo 1` works. In `wine cmd` at least.

Answer (score 3):

The `\` sign makes the interpreter interpret the next sign as a *character* instead of an *identifier*.

You see it a lot in code as well:

```
"Hello \"World\""
```

this is *interpreted* as

```
Hello "World"
```

in your example, in order to pass the arguments to `cmd`, it needs to be enclosed in "". But since the arguments to `cmd` contains " (and this would end the enclosure) they are appended by `\`. If the "" would not have been there, the `/k dir \"%userprofile%\"` would have been interpreted as arguments to `runas`, not to `cmd`.

The reason why they are enclosing the %userprofile% is because this is an environmental variable and will be replaced by text which could contain spaces, which (for the same reason as above) would make the argument to `cmd` incorrect.

Comment: Looks to me like RunAs "needs" quotes when that second parameter, the program parameter, has a space. Otherwise it thinks it is being given more parameters than it is.  In theory, runas could have been written(I mean coded) to take it to the end, as one parameter no quotes necessary.    In contrast to this. cmd.exe e.g. cmd /c dir a b     That takes -dir a b- as one parameter.

Comment: Also, a more complex point, it looks to me like runas could've done without \"  But can't because it is taking the " as start and the next " as end.    If it just took the outter-most ones as beginning and end, then it wouldn't need middle ones to be \" e.g. even a nasty looking line like this C:\>runas /user:Administrator "runas /user:Administrator \"cmd /k dir \"%userprofile%\"\" "   If it were all " and no \"  then theoretically you can still process it. But not so because of the way runas has been written.

Comment: @barlop: Don't think of `cmd` as the argument to runas, because it is not. The argument to runas is `cmd /k dir \"%userprofile%\"`. I don't have the time now, but give me a couple of hours and I should be able to explain a simple C++ program to you and how those programs interpret arguments. I think it would be more clear. So, **answer bound to change**

Comment: Actually I may understand and just wasn't clear. I'm aware of the main method and argsv. I heard that they take all arguments in their first element? is that right?   
Regarding me mentioning cmd.exe, there is an ambiguity whether I mean cmd.exe in that line, or the outter cmd.exe that the line is written in.  The only time I mentioned cmd.exe in what I wrote in these comments, was  cmd /c dir a b      And i'm right that -dir a b- is 1 parameter. But I have been told(don't know if correctly) that all windows programs get all their args as 1 string, presumably argsv[0],then split it themselves

Comment: I could clarify the ambiguity by ensuring that the open shell is cmd.exe,  and doing copy cmd.exe cmd2.exe, then making any line  I write have cmd2.exe instead of cmd.exe  
e.g. cmd2.exe /k dir a b     And for the runas line  also with cmd2 in it instead of cmd.  
 C:\>runas /user:Administrator "runas /user:Administrator \"cmd2 /k dir \"%userprofile%\"\" "
So.I'd think  cmd2 /c dir a b
<-- that -dir a b- is one paramater. Though yes, like any command, cmd2 will be given the whole thing -/c dir a b-  (in argsv[0]?), and cmd2 will determine which is which.

Comment: (I do have some programming knowledge.. java in the past, though not c). but i'm familiar with the concept of a main method which takes an array. If that helps.. thanks.

Comment: ok. now I found some code that shows it. I can see how it's split and delimited. 
http://pastebin.com/28Q2Wxxr
    $ ./w sfd,sdf,sdf p
argv[0]=./w   argv[1]=sdf,sdf,sdf   argv[2]=p

Comment: ./w "sdf,sdf,sdf p"    argv[0]=./w  argv[1]=sdf,sdf,sdf p

Comment: Interestingly
C:\>cmd2 /k dir a b     and C:\>cmd2 /k "dir a b"
Both display the same thing.
So perhaps cmd2 concatenates them all into one parameter like "dir a b".  Just as cmd /? says it takes a switch then one string.

Comment: Runas I see, doesn't combine its C style parameters like cmd2 does. So, needs the quotes. Though in theory, it could've been coded to combine them and not need quotes.

Comment: That's my thinking anyway(inspired by your comments).. don't know if i'm right

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are after.. sorry.. But it is great that you understand the main function. In java it is the same thing, the String[] args are interpreted the same way in java as in C++. and all between "" will be one argument. And no, the arguments are passed in separately (divided by spaces), not as one. The program does not have to divide them itself. I am not familiar with cmd2. Could you rephrase your findings in your answer to make it more clear?The best I think would be if you write "Why is this row <something> interpreted like this <> and not like this <>"

Comment: I agree.. I see from the C code that programs don't get it all in one parameter.
cmd2.exe is just a copy of cmd.exe , but called cmd2.exe But I can use cmd.exe instead of cmd2.exe
so. i'm asking if you agree that..
cmd /c dir a b    <-- is same as  cmd "dir a b" , proving that it takes the parameters dir,a,b  and combines them into one. 
Runas on the other hand, does not combine any of its parameters(unless one uses quotes of course). It could in theory combine its program parameter and then not require quotes. Rather like cmd combines some parameters.

Comment: Wondering if you agree with that.

Comment: @Michael, if you want it in Why form.. I could ask.
Why is  cmd /c dir a b  
interpreted like cmd /c "dir a b"
Whereas  with runas, the program parameter(See runas /?) wants quotes.
I think runas could've easily been coded to not want them. Since looks to me like theoretically it shouldn't need them.

Comment: well then. that is another question. but now I understand what you mean. I do not know the reason for this, but I'll see if I can find anything. anyway, the reason why ` \ ` is there is because in between `""` the ` \ ` sign is interpreted as a special character.